# Extension of the session to one year

Tags: php, session, cookies

If I set the session length to one year, would I actually avoid logging out for the next year, even if I turned off my browser or computer?

Edit: Am I able to get the effect of not logging out or auto-logging in any other way?

Comment: I think that it will still delete them time to time

Comment: There are some factors to be considered: Web server configuration, php web server configuration, type of session cookie, and browser / cookie configuration. Given the web server and php are configured to persist sessions, to not clean them up before a year has passed, you use permanent cookies and the browser keeps them that long, this should be possible.

Comment: sound good, but it seems to be a complex subject

Answer (score -1):

Session will be removed after you close browser or after Apache reset

Comment: Am I able to get the effect of not logging out or auto-logging in any other way?

Comment: you could use cookie for it ($_COOKIE)

Comment: That is not gererally true. Depending on the php configuration, php will persist sessions and they will be valid even after a web server restart